# GIT checkout unambiguous ref

Tags: bash, git, git-bash

I have a branch and a tag both named `test`.
If I have an unambiguous ref like `heads/test` or `refs/heads/test`, how can I checkout without going into detached state?

```
git checkout heads/test
```

I want to save the current HEAD state and later return to it:

```
# Exit if dirty

# Save HEAD
ref=$(git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD)
if [ -z "$ref" ] ; then # Detached
    ref=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
fi
echo $ref

# Do Stuff that changes HEAD
git checkout master

# Restore HEAD
git checkout $ref
```

::Edited for clarity::

Comment: To checkout the branch, `git checkout test`. To checkout the tag, `git checkout tags/test`.

Comment: @ElpieKay So you are saying I have to strip off the prefix, but only if it is `refs/heads/`. I thought there would be a plumbing way to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** [Adamarla notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49071278/git-checkout-unambiguous-ref#comment85153790_49073450) that `git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD` misbehaves in this ambiguous-reference situation.  For instance:

```
$ mkdir t
$ cd t
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
$ echo test symref > README
$ git add README 
$ git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) ee3448a] initial
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
$ git branch test
$ git tag test
$ git checkout test
warning: refname 'test' is ambiguous.
Switched to branch 'test'
$ git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD
heads/test
```

so my original answer below has an important error.  I'd use a slight variant on the OP's alternative:

```
if headRef=$(git symbolic-ref -q HEAD); then
    headRef=${headRef#refs/heads/}
else
    headRef=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
fi
```

---

Note that:

- `git symbolic-ref` errors (returns a failed status, as well as not printing the symbolic reference) when `HEAD` is not a symbolic reference:

  ```
  if ! ref=$(git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD); then
      ... HEAD is detached ...
  ```

  (In other words, you do not need a separate zero-length string test.)
- `HEAD` can *only* be a symbolic reference to a branch name, not a tag name.
- Most Git commands behave as described in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html), in that the bare name `test` will resolve to the commit pointed-to by `refs/tags/test` rather than `refs/heads/test`.  The `git checkout` command, however, behaves differently: `git checkout test` will prefer the branch.

Thus, if the `git symbolic-ref` succeeds, your short reference is suitable to pass to `git checkout`.  If it fails, you do need to run `git rev-parse HEAD` to get the hash ID to pass to the later `git checkout`.

Comment: If the `git symbolic-ref` succeeds, it will have the `heads/` prefix for ambiguous names, so it is not suitable for `checkout`

Comment: @Adamarla: Gack. That's bad behavior from `git symbolic-ref`!

Comment: I didn't know that (#) way to do prefix removal. It is clearer than using the character index

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

> Branch to checkout; if it refers to a branch (i.e., a name that, when prepended with "refs/heads/", is a valid ref), then that branch is checked out. Otherwise, if it refers to a valid commit, your HEAD becomes "detached" and you are no longer on any branch (see below for details).

So:  If there exist both a branch and a tag with the name `test`, then `git checkout test` will checkout the branch without detaching.  It is true that git gives a warning, but it still will consistently behave this way.

But on the other hand, if you give it *anything other than* a "branch name" as defined above - which includes explicitly qualifying the branch, as in `heads/test` - then it detaches.

So it seems if you have `heads/test` and want to check out without detaching, the (porcelain) procedure is to strip the `heads/` off and just `checkout test`.

If you *really* don't want to do that... well, I don't know a "safe" alternative that's any better.

You could use `git symbolic-ref`

```
git symbolic-ref -m "Checkout test" HEAD refs/heads/test
git reset HEAD -- .
git checkout -- .
```

but notice you have to *fully* qualify the ref in this case - so you still can't just use `heads/test`.  Also if you don't manually provide a "reason" in a `-m` argument, you'll muck up the reflog.  And you have to then update the index and work tree.  You could write a script or alias to do all that, I guess.

Or you could directly manipulate the `.git/HEAD` file, but if you mess it up git will no longer recognize the repo until you fix it.

Also, you said:

> Checking out tags/test works fine.

Not sure what this means, since (a) your question was how to check out `heads/test` without entering detached head, but (b) checking out a tag *always* enters detached head.  And:

> I am getting the ref from:
>
> ```
> git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD
> ```

Under what circumstances would this return `tags/test`?  Maybe I misunderstood because you put that on the same line where you were talking about checkout out the tag... do you mean that `git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD` is returning `heads/test`, and you're storing that and later trying to check out to it?

In that case, see above; but also in that case, you could leave out the `--short` and at least that would be one step closer to making the `symbolic-ref` approach work...

Answer (score 1):

I was hoping for a plumbing checkout command that would handle branch checkout from a qualified ref, but have come up with this workaround:

```
# Save Checkout
refBranch=$(git symbolic-ref -q HEAD)
refDetach=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
echo "refBranch [$refBranch]"
echo "refDetach [$refDetach]"

# Do Stuff
git checkout master --quiet
echo "Now on [$(git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD)]"

# Restore Checkout
if [[ ${refBranch:0:11} == "refs/heads/" ]] ; then
    echo "Checkout Branch [${refBranch:11}]"
    git checkout ${refBranch:11} --quiet
else # Detached
    echo "Checkout Detach [$refDetach]"
    git checkout $refDetach --quiet
fi
```

Or if we are guaranteed to always get the `refs/heads/` prefix:

```
# Save Checkout
if headRef=$(git symbolic-ref -q HEAD); then
    headRef=${headRef:11}
else
    headRef=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
fi
echo "headRef [${headRef}]"

# Do Stuff
git checkout master --quiet
echo "Now on [$(git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD)]"

# Restore Checkout
git checkout $headRef --quiet
```

Comment: *I was hoping for a plumbing checkout command ...* There probably should be one, but in the absence of one, `git checkout -q $headRef`, with headRef set using your method or mine, will do. Note that you could build one out of `git symbolic-ref` and `git update-ref`—you would again need the two cases—plus `git read-tree` plus `git checkout-index`, but I don't think it's worth attempting to assemble these when `git checkout -q` suffices.